# How do I handle Twilio async transcription processes

Tags: node.js, twilio

I'm a Twilio newbie. I'm using Node.js and Firebase. I have my workflow functioning with dmtf but I'm scratching my head as far as doing a recording, transcribing it, then playing it back to the caller for final approval or re-recording. Additionally I'm using the IBM Watson add on to do voice Spanish transcription. Before all is said and done I need to do the records, get a transcription for either English or Spanish, re-present what was transcribed to caller and then finish up final processing.  Right now my Record attributes are:

```
{
      'maxLength':    30,
      'finishOnKey':  '#',
      'timeout':      30,
      'transcribeCallback': 'procTranscribe',
      'recordingStatusCallbackMethod':'procRecordingStatusCallBack',
      'recordingStatusCallbackEvent':'completed'
 }
```

The only function getting hit is procTranscribe, and while at its end it responds with twiml that should move it on to the next function in the work flow, all it does is repeat.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where's the relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's a few things here. The transcription callback is asynchronous to the call itself, so returning TwiML will not affect the call.

If you want to keep the person on the call waiting (`<Enqueue>`d and listening to hold music, for example) for the callback, you will need to trigger the call to [move to the next TwiML by updating the call with the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#update-a-call-resource) when you receive the webhook.

The other thing is that the asynchronous nature of the callback also means that there's no guarantee on how long it will take for that callback to return. To get over this you could use the status callback webhook to [generate a call back](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#create-a-call-resource) to the user to complete the transaction.